# Generated APK in React Native Doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I had a problem generating the APK of my application with react native, I got that error, I already made my keystore and executed the command npx react-native build-android --mode=release but I don't understand what it is, can you help me?

error Failed to build the app.
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:bundleRelease
at makeError (/Users/azael/Documents/Proyectos/Perca/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
at module.exports.sync (/Users/azael/Documents/Proyectos/Perca/node_modules/execa/index.js:194:17)
at build (/Users/azael/Documents/Proyectos/Perca/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/buildAndroid/index.js:95:22)
at Object.buildAndroid [as func] (/Users/azael/Documents/Proyectos/Perca/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/buildAndroid/index.js:87:10)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/azael/Documents/Proyectos/Perca/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:111:9)

Generated APK ReactNAtive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvpfk.png)